# Failed - pip install bitermplus

Tags: python, windows, nlp

Was trying to install bitermplus package using `pip install bitermplus` and faced this error.

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip install bitermplus
Collecting bitermplus
  Using cached bitermplus-0.4.0.tar.gz (591 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bitermplus) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bitermplus) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bitermplus) (0.29.21)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bitermplus) (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bitermplus) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->bitermplus) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->bitermplus) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas->bitermplus) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->bitermplus) (0.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->bitermplus) (2.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: bitermplus
  Building wheel for bitermplus (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\BOSS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuuizeve7'
       cwd: C:\Users\BOSS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ntg1_x34\bitermplus_df72ac5434cc44a9a700f384afcbf612
  Complete output (44 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\plot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  running egg_info
  writing src\bitermplus.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\bitermplus.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src\bitermplus.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src\bitermplus.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\bitermplus.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'src\bitermplus.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying src\bitermplus\btm.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\btm.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\metrics.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  copying src\bitermplus\metrics.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus
  running build_ext
  building 'bitermplus.btm' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\bitermplus
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\programdata\anaconda3\include -Ic:\programdata\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/bitermplus/btm.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/bitermplus/btm.obj -fopenmp
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
  btm.c
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(2290): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(2323): warning C4013: 'drand48' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(3357): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(3366): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(3435): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(3607): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(4635): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
  src/bitermplus/btm.c(4712): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\programdata\anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:c:\programdata\anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_btm build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/bitermplus/btm.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus\btm.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/bitermplus\btm.cp38-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/fopenmp'; ignored
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/bitermplus\btm.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/bitermplus\btm.cp38-win_amd64.exp
  btm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol drand48
  build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitermplus\btm.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitermplus
Failed to build bitermplus
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bitermplus which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Not sure if its a version compatability problem of something else. Anyone has relevant experiecne on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has been resolved in the new version of this package (0.5.1). If you still get an error, please post an issue on GitHub.